# Installing Android SDK $(^Name) appcrash error

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to install androids SDK + the AVD manager on the windows 7 platform and a $(^Name)  error is coming back after the installation wizard fails. Under the 'more description link-option, a defined 'appcrash' has accrued. How do i resolve this issue, I've tried numerous attempts!

Comment: I suggest you install Eclipse, and install ADK Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install Eclipse, and install ADK Eclipse plugin. [Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) for more details on how to do it.